# tree implementation using linked list,with parent pointer,first chil pointer and siblings pointer in c

Tags: pointers, tree, linked-list, children, insertion

I want help in linked list implementation of a tree. A tree node has three child.
using pointers: `Parent`, `Siblings` and `FirstChild`.

I have tried making it but couldn't get it to work. I need help in inserting new nodes

```
void InsertFirstChild(Node newNode)
{
    newNode.m_Parent = this;
    newNode.m_NextSibling = m_FirstChild;

    if (m_FirstChild != null)
        m_FirstChild.m_PrevSibling = newNode;
    else
        m_LastChild = newNode;

    m_FirstChild = newNode;
}
```

Comment: i think you need to change your data structure

Comment: Is this C or C++? The question says "C" but you are using "this" within the function/method.